Selective loading error - property from hash lookup, found 15
when doing selective loading I have noticed that I often  get an error such as
property from hash lookup, found 15, given Name
 filter: {
          property_query:[
                          {'$like': ['?Name', "'%ST02%'"]}
                        ]}

I assume its because the attribute Name is stored in multiple categories or over multiple levels and that creates different hashes for it. Does anyone know how I over come this?

Unfortunately, this is the known limitation of the selective loading that doesn't support multiple property hashes, as far as I know.
I would advise you to list all possible property hashes related to the Name fields like below as a workaround.
let model = await viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, {
  filter: {
    property_query: [
      { $like: ['s.props.p8b45535a', "'%ST02%'"] },
      { $like: ['s.props.p74eb4bc3', "'%ST02%'"] },
      { $like: ['s.props.p153cb174', "'%ST02%'"] },
      
      //! ... add other name related properties hshses here
    ]
  }
});

More specifically, we can do the following as the workaround:
let query = [{
  $like: ['?Name', "'%ST02%'"]
}];
let fakeLoadedModel = await viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, {
  filter: {
    property_query: query
  }
});

await viewer.waitForLoadDone();

const propHashes = await fakeLoadedModel.getPropertyHashes();
viewer.unloadDocumentNode(fakeLoadedModel.getDocumentNode());

const matches = JSON.stringify(query).matchAll(/(["'])\?([\w\d\s]+)\1/g);
for (const match of matches) {
  const attributeSearchString = match[2].trim();
  query = propHashes.filter(propHash => propHash[1] === attributeSearchString)
    .map(propHash => {
      return {
        $like: [`s.props.${propHash[0]}`, query[0]['$like'][1]]
      };
    });
}


let model = await viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, {
  filter: {
    property_query: query
  }
});

await viewer.waitForLoadDone();

